# Can a continuous bounded variation function be $C^0$-reparametrized to be continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be a function of bounded variation. We say that $g$ is a $C^0$ reparametrization if $g = f \circ s$ for $s$ a continuous increasing bijection from a finite interval $I$ to $[0, 1]$.

**Question:** Does a continuous function of bounded variation always admit a $C^0$ reparametrization that is continuously differentiable?

*Remark: Reparametrizing by the (inverse of) the variation of $f$ gives a $1$-Lipschitz function, which is at least differentiable a.e.*

Comment: Try with $f(x) =\int_0^x\sin(1/t)dt=\int_0^x\max(0,\sin(1/t))dt+\int_0^x\min(0,\sin(1/t))dt$

Comment: Why is this function not reparametrizable?

Comment: Thanks to your remark, the question reduces to whether a Lipchitz function can be reparametrized so as to become $C^1$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Non-constant $C^1$ functions have intervals of monotonicity: if $f'(x_0)\neq 0$ then $f$ is monotone on some interval $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$; this follows from the inverse function theorem. Evidently monotone continuous reparameterizations preserve this property. But a function of
bounded variation does not have to have such intervals. See examples in the comments.

Comment: Ah very nice invariant you found! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: $f$ is **continuous**and bounded variation.

Comment: $f(x)=x-\mu([0,x])$, with $\mu$ singular continuous and $\mu(U)>0$ for all open $U$ would work.

Comment: Similar to @ChristianRemling’s example, one could take $f$ be absolutely continuous with $f’ = 1_U - 1_{U^c}$, with $U$ and $U^c$ having nonzero measure in every open interval.